Prove if group $G = [G,G]$, then $G/Z(G)$ is centerless
There is a hint on the book:

Consider natural map $\pi:G \to G/Z(G)$, define $\zeta^2(G) := \pi^{-1}(Z(G/Z(G)))$. Use the three subgroups lemma with $L = \zeta^2(G)$ and $H=K=G$

And here is the the three subgroups lemma:

Let $H,K,L$ be subgroups of $G$, define $[H,K,L] = \langle \{ [h,[k,l]]| h \in H, k\in K, l\in L \} \rangle$. If $[H,K,L][K,L,H] \leqslant N \lhd G$, then $[L,H,K] \leqslant N$

My attempt:
Our goal should be proving $\zeta^2(G) = Z(G)$
Since $\zeta^2(G) := \pi^{-1}(Z(G/Z(G)))$, by correspondence theorem, $Z(G) \lhd \zeta^2(G) \lhd G$. If we can show that $\zeta^2(G) \lhd Z(G)$, then we are done.
Therefore, if we can give $[G,G,\zeta^2(G)][G,\zeta^2(G),G] = \{e\}$, by the three subgroups lemma $[\zeta^2(G),G,G]= \{e\}$. Since $[G,G] = G$, $[\zeta^2(G),G]= \{e\}$, then $\zeta^2(G) \lhd Z(G)$.
However, I am not able to prove $[G,G,\zeta^2(G)][G,\zeta^2(G),G] = \{e\}$. The only thing came in my mind is $[G,G,\zeta^2(G)][G,\zeta^2(G),G]/Z(G) = e$ so that $[G,G,\zeta^2(G)][G,\zeta^2(G),G] \leqslant Z(G)$.
Thank you

This result (that that the quotient $G/Z(G)$ is centerless if $[G,G]=G$) is known as Grün's lemma. Also, groups $G$ with $[G,G]=G$ are known as perfect groups.

@Geoffrey Trang Thank you for noticing the terminology

You are not quoting the Three Subgroup Lemma in the right way, it should be:
if two of the subgroups $[H,K,L]$, $[K,L,H]$ or $[L,H,K]$ are contained in the normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, then so is the third.
By the way, the upper central series is denoted with a subscript like $\zeta_2(G)$, not with an upper one (then it gets a total different meaning). And $Z(G)=\zeta_1(G)$. 
Anyhow: $[G,[G,\zeta_2(G)]] \subseteq [G,Z(G)]=1$ and $[G,[\zeta_2(G),G]] \subseteq [G,Z(G)]=1$, so $[\zeta_2(G),[G,G]]=1$ and I think you can finish it now.

Thank you, I get it
